# Image of size more than 3 MB not getting uploaded using webservices .asmx

Tags: silverlight-3.0, web-services

I am trying to upload images using a webservice from silverlight. I am first converting the images into stram of bytes and then trying to upload them. I am able to upload image of size 2.5 MB. But not more than that.It gives me "The remote server returned an error: NotFound" error.
What could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config file, in your system.web section, try:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" maxRequestLength="4096" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1" />
```

This will allow files up to 4Mb.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just the maxRequestLength="8096" though. :)